# How do I add time to a delayed task?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, filesystemwatcher

I have a process where I spin up `FileSystemWatcher` to watch the filesystem for incoming files.

I set up a delay with `Task.Delay` that cancels the FSW either when cancellation token is set or after time expires (for instance 10 minutes).

```
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

// start the timer
RunAfterDelay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), cts.Token, () =>
{
    // get rid of the watcher
    watcher.Dispose();
});

private async void RunAfterDelay(TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token, Action action)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay, token);
    if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

But I'd like to configure it in a way to be able to add additional delay everytime new file appears. So effectively some kind of sliding expiration delay.

Comment: cancel and recreate?

Comment: That was my thought initially but I'd like to keep the FSW running if possible because there could be files incoming every few seconds (or less) and this would result in many cancellations and recreations. What I'd like to achieve essentially is having the FSW running since first file comes and all the way until last files comes + 10 minutes.

Comment: no, sorry, cancel and recreate the _running task_. so a `restartTimeoutCancellation` cancel.. Let me see if I can formulate it into an understandable sentence :)

Comment: [would this work?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e9VSUA)

Comment: the provided action delegate never runs?

Comment: yeah, there seems to be some issue with dotnetfiddle and using Task.Delay. see if you can trigger the expected outcome with TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)

Comment: Is it what you would expect though? In that case I'll add it as an answer. If it's not working for you, would you mind maybe explaining why?

Comment: Let me try it in my project, but not right now in a few hours. But seems close.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to work, I copied it to a new console project and it never hits the Hello even after extending the timespan. Also another thing: I'm using this in an MVC/Web API controller so I guess the CTS should be kept around as a static instance - my guess.

Answer (score 2):

You could slightly change your delay method in order to be able to shift the execution time.

I created a small example for you.

You then can just make a "delayed dispose" of the `FileSystemWatcher` in a simple way:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
await watcher.DisposeDelayed(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), cts.Token);
```

I created an extension method `DisposeDelayed` for the `FileSystemWatcher`:

```
static class Utilities
{
    public static async Task DisposeDelayed(this FileSystemWatcher watcher, TimeSpan inactivePeriod, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        DateTime disposalTime = DateTime.Now + inactivePeriod;
        FileSystemEventHandler postponeTrigger = (s, e) => disposalTime = DateTime.Now + inactivePeriod;
        watcher.Created += postponeTrigger;
        watcher.Changed += postponeTrigger;
        // add here other event handlers you need to postpone the disposal

        try
        {
            await RunAtTimePoint(() => disposalTime, ct, watcher.Dispose).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            // don't forget to unsubscribe from each event
            watcher.Created -= postponeTrigger;
            watcher.Changed -= postponeTrigger;
        }
    }

    // You can also use this method for other tasks if you need
    public static async Task RunAtTimePoint(Func<DateTime> execTimeProvider, CancellationToken token, Action action)
    {
        int delayTime;
        do
        {
            // first, calculate the time left until the execution
            DateTime execTime = execTimeProvider();
            TimeSpan timeLeft = execTime - DateTime.Now;

            // we delay in 1000 ms chunks;
            // but if the delay time is less, we need to handle that
            delayTime = (int)Math.Min(1000d, timeLeft.TotalMilliseconds);
            if (delayTime > 0)
            {
                // don't forget the ConfigureAwait call:
                // we don't need the context switch each time
                await Task.Delay(delayTime, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        while (delayTime > 0 && !token.IsCancellationRequested);

        if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having second thoughts to go with this code, looks rather complicated.